# Improving performance in a powershell script

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to get a list of archived events from evtx files, and use REST to post the data after modifying the format.

Here are the results I get on a Windows 7 x64 system:

```
Measure-Command {Get-WinEvent -ea SilentlyContinue -path "C:\evtx\arindam_security_1.evtx" -Oldest -MaxEvents 500|select *,@{ Name="Event Data"; Expression={([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data }} }

TotalSeconds      : 2.3954976
TotalMilliseconds : 2395.4976
```

Is there any way I can improve on this?

I have already tried using filterhashtable for the same and it took around 5 secs - almost double the last result.

When I use REST to post the data:

```
Measure-Command {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://[ip:port]/events -Body $content -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}

PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\sarindam\Documents\testrest.ps1


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 24
Milliseconds      : 365
Ticks             : 243658910
TotalDays         : 0.000282012627314815
TotalHours        : 0.00676830305555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.406098183333333
TotalSeconds      : 24.365891
TotalMilliseconds : 24365.891
```

24 secs to send the same batch of 500 events using REST. Can there be anything done with this query to improve the performance?

I read in some blog that `Invoke-WebRequest` gives better results when it runs on 32 bit. Haven't tested this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve this issue. Anyone facing similar issues should think of writing it in C# instead of powershell.

We wrote a custom dll which would take the evt/evtx files and convert them into a format which is understandable by our platform. We consumed the custom dll as part of a powershell script to loop through the evt/evtx files.

The performance we achieved has been 100+ EPS. The initial EPS we got from Powershell was around 18 EPS and with multi-threading we could achieve around 80 EPS.

Comment: One more note, you may think 80 EPS is a good number but we had some memory leak issues when we tried multi threading in powershell.